# Submitting New Version Of The App To The App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I have an iPhone app that was accepted in the App Store almost a month ago. Now i have updated my app with some new features and added iOS 7 support etc.

This is actually the first very first time i am going to submit a new version of the same app to the App Store.

As far as it seems, i have to go to iTunes Connect > Manage Your Apps, select the app and then click on "Add Version" and add the version number and whats changed in the new version. Go back and add the updated screenshots and then using Xcode, i can submit it for the approval.

The question is that is there anything else that i am missing and that i should do in order to submit the new version of the app? As i said i am doing it for the very first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do now is to update the version number and the build number in your Xcode application, archive your app and submit on the AppStore.

[image]

On iTunes Connect you set the new version number :

[image]

Comment: i don't need to update the changes and version number in iTunes Connect and manage apps?

Comment: and new app icon in the App Store and new screenshots too?

Comment: after creating the new version on iTunes Connect, you can change the new icon in the `Version Information` section and screenshot in the section `Metadata and Uploads`

Comment: and last thing i need to ask: Previously the screenshots were without the status bar, i mean i had to cut the top 20 pixels to remove the status bar. Do i need to do the same with iOS 7 or not?

Comment: you don't have the choice, provide the screenshot with the size asked by Apple.

Comment: well, for example for 3.5 inch devices, it says "Screenshots for 3.5-inch iPhone and iPod touch Retina display must be 960x640, 960x600, 640x960 or 640x920 pixels". What i am asking is should i upload screens from any of the asked sizes?

Comment: if you application is in `portrait` use 960x640 (640x960 for `landscape`), and use 960x600 and 640x920 if your application doesn't have `status bar`

Answer (score 2):

Things you may wan't to consider:

- submitting any new in-app purchases with the new version of the app
- make sure your app version and short app version is higher than the one in the version currently in the app store, otherwise you will not pass validation
- run validation before submitting so you can see if you get any warnings, sometimes there may be collision with Apple private apis. If they are in your code, I'd suggest to rename your methods